# htaccess file using the rewriterule to make the urls better

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi I have a website eg website.co.uk

I would like a htaccess file using the rewriterule to make the urls better

Current URL

```
Website.co.uk?campaign=holiday&affiliate=1
```

the parameters (holiday & no 1) will change, depending on where the inbound link comes from

sometimes there will only be 1 parameter which would be the campaign like below

```
Website.co.uk/holiday
```

sometimes there will be 2 parameters

```
Website.co.uk/holiday/100
```

I have get variables in my php to get the variables on an index.php page

```
$campagin = $_GET['campaign'];
$affiliate = $_GET['affilaite'];
```

The first one has only 1 parameter I.e their might not be an affiliate
Or the May be 2 parameters I.e a campaign and an affiliate

the page they are redirecting to is index.php

In my php it checks if the gets are set but just struggling with rewrite rule

Answer (score 0):

I totally understand your concern, and there is this site, where you could randomly create your `.htaccess` file based on your requirements.

http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Give it a try!

Comment: Nice, wish I had this a long time ago!

Comment: hi, i dont known how to use this one. and i am not expert in web programming

Comment: if any solution of my question then please send me

Answer (score -1):

In the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for redirecting query string URLs to nicer path URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?:index\.php|)\?campaign=([^&]+)&affiliate=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?:index\.php|)\?campaign=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

# internally rewrite path URLs back to query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+)|)$ /index.php?campaign=$1&affiliate=$2 [L]
```